# Enable TokUdb plugin into MySQL or MariaDb in Windows OS

Tags: mysql, windows, installation, mariadb

is there any possibiliy to enable or install **TukUDB** stockage engine for **MariaDb** or **MySQl** database in **Windows** because i found many tutorials how to enable this plugin on Linux but Not in **Windows**?

im trying to install it from MySQL Console but i got many ***message error***:

```
install plugin tokudb soname 'ha_tokudb.so';
```

errors console:

```
install plugin tokudb soname 'ha_tokudb.so';
[Err] 1126 - Can't open shared library 'C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.0\lib\plugin\ha_tokudb.so.dll' (errno: 2, The specified module could not be found.
)
```

thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

Those "*.so" files wont work on Windows. Their website says that you'll need to contact them if you want to run it on Windows: https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/02/01/1773/#Technical

> Please contact Tokutek at support@tokutek.com for Windows support [...]